# What's the simplest way to connect Silverlight app with SQL Database

Tags: sql, silverlight

I am building a Silverlight 4 app that's going to be out of browser with elevated privileges - what's going to be the simplest and most direct way for the clients to access the SQL DB on the Server.
I need to finish the project as soon as possible and I don't know how to use RIA Services - so I will and never used Web Based services - I will really appreciate if you give me the simplest and most direct way - and link to some sort of explanation about how you implement it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using RIA is not so complicated as it seems at a first sight...

Look into links below:

- [Get Started with WCF RIA Services](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/advanced-techniques/wcf-ria-services/get-started-with-wcf-ria-services);
- [Using WCF RIA Services](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/advanced-techniques/wcf-ria-services/using-wcf-ria-services);
- [WCF RIA Services](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/advanced-techniques/wcf-ria-services/wcf-ria-services-%28silverlight-quickstart%29)

Second article will be the most useful in short terms.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use web services:

http://forums.silverlight.net/t/93899.aspx/1

That link has a tutorial, but this is a more recent one on how to do it:  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/CntDbSlght.aspx

Comment: What about - since silverlight can create a bridge to HTML - is this possible to use ASP.NET to get the data from SQL server and somehow to pass it to Silverlight? Please help me do that - how to pass data and not just activate functions from HTML to Silverlight.

Comment: Have you looked at LightSwitch yet? It's supposed to be a simpler way to create application with Silverlight.  I haven't used it, but I've heard good things about it.  Maybe you should give it a try.  Here's a link:  http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/lightswitch